# How to edit data in GridView using asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am binding data to the gridview from SQL server but having some issues with the Edit.

Here is my model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Gridview_BugTracker.Models
{
    public class BugTracker_DataHelper
      {

        public static List<BugTracker_DataHelper> GetList{get;set;}

          public string ProjectId { get; set; }
          public string projectName { get; set; }           
          public string Description { get; set; }
           public  string status { get; set; }         
        }     

   }
```

Here is my controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using Gridview_BugTracker.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Gridview_BugTracker.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Projects/


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var bugedlist = GetList(); 
            return View(bugedlist);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int projectId)
        {
             BugTracker_DataHelper bugedit = new BugTracker_DataHelper();           
             var edit = EditList();
             bugedit.ProjectId =Convert.ToString(projectId);
             return View(edit);      
        }

        public List<BugTracker_DataHelper> GetList()
        {
            var modelList = new List<BugTracker_DataHelper>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Projects", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var model = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
                    model.ProjectId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjectId"].ToString();
                    model.projectName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["projectName"].ToString();
                    model.Description = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                    model.status = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
                    modelList.Add(model);
                }
            }
            return modelList;
        }

     [HttpPost]   
    public ActionResult EditList()
        {
            var editlist = new List<BugTracker_DataHelper>();
            using (SqlConnection editconn=new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS"))
            {
                editconn.Open();
                var modeledit = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
                SqlCommand ecmd = new SqlCommand("EditGetList", editconn);
                ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                ecmd.Parameters.Add("@projectID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = modeledit.ProjectId;
                Object prjid = ecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                editconn.Close();                 

                editlist.Add(modeledit);
            }
            return View(editlist);
        }
```

Gridview Code

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>         
        <th>
            ProjectName
        </th>

        <th>
           Status
        </th>       

    </tr>

 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %> 

    <tr> 

        <td> 
            <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.projectName) %> 
        </td> 

        <td>
         <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.status) %>
        </td>

         <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { projectId = item.projectName})%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { projectId = item.Description })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { projectId = item.status })%>
        </td>

        </tr>

       <%} %>

</table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/SiteMaster.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    editindex
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>editindex</h2>


    <fieldset>
        <legend>EDit</legend>        

        <div class="editor-label">
           <%:  Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.ProjectId) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model) %>
           <%:  Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
           <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)%>
        </div>


         <div class="editor-label">
           <%:  Html.LabelFor(model => model.status) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <%:   Html.EditorFor(model => model.status) %>
          <%:    Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status) %>
        </div>   


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

When i click the edit button I am getting the following error.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'projectId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'Gridview_BugTracker.Controllers.ProjectsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be in the following line.

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { projectId = item.projectName})%>
```

Your edit action is expecting an Int but you are passing it what I am assuming is a string. So its never binding correctly and therefore you end up with a null projectId.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProjectName is declared as string
      public string projectName { get; set; }
```

While editing the item you should be passing an int but you are passing a string

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { projectId = item.projectName})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int projectId)
{
     BugTracker_DataHelper bugedit = new BugTracker_DataHelper();           
     var edit = EditList();
     bugedit.ProjectId =Convert.ToString(projectId);
     return View(edit);      
}
```

I think Your problem lies in the method, the method should be rewritten as below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int projectId)
{
     BugTracker_DataHelper bugedit = new BugTracker_DataHelper();           
     bugedit.ProjectId =Convert.ToString(projectId);
     var edit = EditList();
     return View(edit);      
}
```